# Proving that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{n+1}{2n}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}  \frac{n+1}{2n}$ diverges but am having trouble. My idea is to find a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums $(S_n)$ that diverges. I have $(S_n)$ as $(1 + \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k  \frac{2+k}{2+2k})$ but am still stuck. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: A necessary condition for convergence of an infinite series is that the general term approach zero.

Comment: Right, I tried proving that the sequence doesn't converge to 0 but can't work out the details.

Comment: The absolute value of the $n^{\text{th}}$ term is $\frac{n+1}{2n}\gt\frac n{2n}=\frac12.$ Note that $a_n\to0$ implies $|a_n|\to0.$ If $|a_n|\ge\frac12$ for all $n$ then $|a_n|$ does not approach  $0$ and neither does $a_n.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do in this case is note that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{(n+1)}{(2n)}}=\frac{1}{2}$$ which means that since the sequence doesn't approach $0$, the alternating series itself must, as a result, diverge.

Comment: It seems like you're using the converse of the alternating series test to prove divergence---which you can't do.

Comment: It's called the divergence test. You can do it, even for non-alternating series.

Comment: @zuggurism Yes, but the sequence of terms in the series is not ((n+1) / (2n)) but rather ((−1)^n+1 (n+1)/2n). So this is the sequence I need to show doesn't converge to 0.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Theorem. $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=0.$

Answer (score 0):

Considering $$a_n=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{ (n+1)}{2 n}$$ use the ratio test $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=-\frac{n (n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\implies \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\sim 1-\frac 1 {n^2}$$  which show that it is  inconclusive.

Now, use [Raabe's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test) $$n \left(\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|-1\right)=\frac{1}{n+2}<1 $$ then divergence.

Comment: With Raabe's test you can only decide whether a series converges absolutely.